# At loading home over SSL a call is made to load wp-admin over http:

Tags: wordpress, ssl

I have FORCE_SSL_ADMIN and FORCE_SSL_LOGIN enabled; IS_SSL checked, I still have these insecure errors and warnings:

Laden van gemengde actieve inhoud ‘http://[site]/wp-admin/’ geblokkeerd[Meer info] 
Laden van gemengde (onveilige) vensterinhoud ‘http://[site]/wp-content/uploads/2018/07/cartnew-icn.png’ op een beveiligde pagina[Meer info] jquery.js:3:7276

English:

Mixed content http;?? .../wp-admin blocked.

Mixed content on an image, for which I can't locate the place where it is defined (theme is salient/nectar with woocommerce and VisualComposer)

Can anyone help me?
Thanks

Comment: Remove mixed content images and re-upload those. It'll fix your issue.

Comment: Really Simple SSL plugin will resolve these issues without you having to find where the offending images are being called.

Comment: Thanks. I installed Really Simple SSL, Force-SSL-URL-Schme and SSL secure content before I posted the question. I followed all the hints I have found on the internet. It is not the image I can't find where it is defined that I worry about, but the unsecure call to wp-admin even before the page get loaded.